# How to refresh table value while select different value in Select box

Tags: jquery, html, json

I want to refresh table value while select different value in Select box. My Issue is when select the select box value Table load the data perfectly then i select the another value Table loaded without refresh the existing value. Ma script is jquery and get data using getjson method.

HTML Code

```
<select id="destinations"  >
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
<table id= "class" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S.No</th>
            <th>Date & Time</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Served Business</th>
            <th>Total Amount</th>
            <th>Parking Rate</th>
            <th>Tip</th>
            <th>Promo Code</th>
            <th>Promo Discount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>                         
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://api.valetpayapp.com/phptest/dashboard_fetch_valet_locations.php?callback=?', 'valetgroup_id=valetgroup_52c36a450a002', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, v) {
        $('#destinations').append('<option value="' + v.ValetLotId + '">' + v.BusinessName + ', ' + v.Address + '</option>');
        });
    });
});
$('select').change( function() {
    var params = { valetlot_id:this.value, start_date:'2014-01-01', end_date:'2014-02-28' };
    var str = jQuery.param( params );
    $.getJSON('http://api.valetpayapp.com/phptest/dashboard_fetch_valet_transactions.php?callback=?',str, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, f) {
        var tblRow = "<tr>"  + "<td>" + f.Date + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Status + "</td>" + "<td> " + f.BusinessName + "</td>" +  "<td>" + f.TotalAmount + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.ParkingRate + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Tip + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.PromoCode + "</td>" + "<td>" +   f.PromoDiscount + "</td>" + "</tr>"
        $(tblRow).appendTo("#class tbody");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Provide us some HTML AND JS code, maybe jsfiddle.net AND SOME COMMITMENT!

Comment: Your question is confusing. By table value, do you mean a specfic cell or the whole table? Do you have any code? Please post it if you do

Comment: <select id="destinations"  >
 <option value=""></option>
</select>

<table id= "class" class="table table-hover">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>S.No</th>
   <th>Date & Time</th>
   <th>Status</th>
   <th>Served Business</th>
   <th>Total Amount</th>
   <th>Parking Rate</th>
   <th>Tip</th>
   <th>Promo Code</th>
   <th>Promo Discount</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>       
 </tbody>
</table>

Comment: @Mr.TK I have update my code here pls check it and do needful help... thanks

Comment: @Ryan B I have update my code here pls check it and do needful help ... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the JSFIDDLE i've done:

http://jsfiddle.net/G5Cb8/3/

You just have to clear tbody of table upon select change:

```
    $('table#class tbody').html('');
```

Comment: I don't think his coming back... :( :D

Comment: Thank u soooooooooo much @Mr.TK ....... its working... I have one more doubt, how to bind first value in select box automatically after loading the web page.

Comment: I have one more [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517021/how-to-get-all-json-values-in-line-chart) Please check the given link do the needful... Thanks @Mr.TK

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/G5Cb8/5/ this should work with this: how to bind first value in select box automatically after loading the web page. But API returns empty json for first option

Comment: hi @Mr.TK i have one more doubt... am set 'start_date' & 'end_date' statically in this code. now am gonna use bootstrap datepicker with this code. my doubt is while am selecting the date rage (eg: 1-1-1014 to 1-3-2014) like this, the table also show the date within the date range. how to get this.