# How to refresh table data while select different value in Select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to refresh table value while select different value in Select box. My Issue is when select the select box value Table load the data perfectly then i select the another value Table loaded without refresh the existing value.

HTML Code

```
<select id="destinations">
   <option value=""></option>
</select>

<table class="table table-hover" id="class">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>S.No</th>
<th>Date &amp; Time</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Served Business</th>
<th>Total Amount</th>
<th>Parking Rate</th>
<th>Tip</th>
<th>Promo Code</th>
<th>Promo Discount</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
<div id="label_CarsParked" class="number"></div>
<div id="label_RevenueWithTip" class="number"></div>
<div id="label_Revenue" class="number"></div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON('http://api.valetpayapp.com/phptest/dashboard_fetch_valet_locations.php?callback=?', 'valetgroup_id=valetgroup_52c36a450a002', function(data) {
$.each(data, function(i, v) {
$('#destinations').append('<option value="' + v.ValetLotId + '">' + v.BusinessName + ', ' + v.Address + '</option>');
});
});
});
$('select').change(function() {
var params = {
valetlot_id: this.value,
start_date: '2014-01-01',
end_date: '2014-02-28'
};
var str = jQuery.param(params);
        $.getJSON('http://api.valetpayapp.com/phptest/dashboard_fetch_valet_transactions.php?callback=?', str, function(data) {
$.each(data, function(i, f) {
var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.Date + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Status + "</td>" + "<td> " + f.BusinessName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.TotalAmount + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.ParkingRate + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Tip + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.PromoCode + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.PromoDiscount + "</td>" + "</tr>"
$(tblRow).appendTo("#class tbody");
});
});
});
```

This is my bootstrap-datepicker script

```
function () {
$('#dashboard-report-range').daterangepicker({
opens: (App.isRTL() ? 'right' : 'left'),
startDate: moment().subtract('days', 29),
endDate: moment(),
minDate: '01/01/2012',
maxDate: '12/31/2014',
dateLimit: {
days: 60
},
showDropdowns: false,
showWeekNumbers: true,
timePicker: false,
timePickerIncrement: 1,
timePicker12Hour: true,
ranges: {
'Today': [moment(), moment()],
'Yesterday': [moment().subtract('days', 1), moment().subtract('days', 1)],
'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 6), moment()],
'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 29), moment()],
'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
'Last Month': [moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'), moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month')]
},
buttonClasses: ['btn'],
applyClass: 'blue',
cancelClass: 'default',
format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
separator: ' to ',
locale: {
applyLabel: 'Apply',
fromLabel: 'From',
toLabel: 'To',
customRangeLabel: 'Custom Range',
daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
firstDay: 1
}
},
function (start, end) {
console.log("Callback has been called!");
$('#dashboard-report-range span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
}
);
$('#dashboard-report-range span').html(moment().subtract('days', 29).format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + moment().format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
$('#dashboard-report-range').show();
}
```

In above getJson method am set the "start_date" "end_date" with static value. My question is how to set the datepicker value in "start_date" "end_date" dynamically. how can i get this. please anybody give jsfiddle example.

Comment: You do not have a `select` element in your HTML.

Comment: @Mosho sry i miss it
<select id="destinations"  >
<option value=""></option>
</select>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to clear the table whenever you make an ajax request for data.

```
$.getJSON('http://api.valetpayapp.com/phptest/dashboard_fetch_valet_transactions.php?callback=?', str, function(data) {

     $("#class tbody").html(''); /*Clearing the table*/

     /*Populating the table*/
     $.each(data, function(i, f) {
         var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.Date + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Status + "</td>" + "<td> " + f.BusinessName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.TotalAmount + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.ParkingRate + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Tip + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.PromoCode + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.PromoDiscount + "</td>" + "</tr>";
         $(tblRow).appendTo("#class tbody");
     });
 });
```

This is the reason why the table isn't refreshing because only the last 3 options in the select will return data from the request and they have the same `valetlot_id` value which is `valetlot_52c3e6c52dd6f`! And the first 2 `valetlot_id` returns an empty array.

To check if the return data is empty, do a check after clearing the table.

```
console.log(data.length);
```

**UPDATE WITH USE OF `daterangepicker`**

HTML for `daterangepicker`

```
<input id="dashboard-report-range" type="text" />
```

To get the date values from the range picker use:

```
$('#dashboard-report-range').data('daterangepicker').startDate
$('#dashboard-report-range').data('daterangepicker').endDate
```

To make the code more maintainable, you should define a function to fetch data and populate the table so that the `select` and `#dashboard-report-range` can share it.

```
$(function () {
        $('#dashboard-report-range').daterangepicker({

            startDate: moment().subtract('days', 29),
            endDate: moment(),
            minDate: '01/01/2012',
            maxDate: '12/31/2014',
            dateLimit: {
                days: 60
            },
            showDropdowns: false,
            showWeekNumbers: true,
            timePicker: false,
            timePickerIncrement: 1,
            timePicker12Hour: true,
            ranges: {
                'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                'Yesterday': [moment().subtract('days', 1), moment().subtract('days', 1)],
                'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 6), moment()],
                'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 29), moment()],
                'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                'Last Month': [moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'), moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month')]
            },
            buttonClasses: ['btn'],
            applyClass: 'blue',
            cancelClass: 'default',
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
            separator: ' to ',
            locale: {
                applyLabel: 'Apply',
                fromLabel: 'From',
                toLabel: 'To',
                customRangeLabel: 'Custom Range',
                daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
                monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
                firstDay: 1
            }
        },
        function (start, end) {
            /*$('#dashboard-report-range span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));*/
            $("#class tbody").getData($('select option:selected').val(), start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            /*Update code */  
        $('#label_CarsParked').getData($('select option:selected').val(), start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        $('#label_RevenueWithTip').getData($('select option:selected').val(), start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        $('#label_Revenue').getData($('select option:selected').val(), start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        });

        $.getJSON('http://api.valetpayapp.com/phptest/dashboard_fetch_valet_locations.php?callback=?', 'valetgroup_id=valetgroup_52c36a450a002', function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                $('#destinations').append('<option value="' + v.ValetLotId + '">' + v.BusinessName + ', ' + v.Address + '</option>');
            });
        });

        $('select').change(function () {
            $("#class tbody").getData($(this).val(), $('#dashboard-report-range').data('daterangepicker').startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), $('#dashboard-report-range').data('daterangepicker').endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            /* Update Code */
            $('#label_CarsParked').getData($('#label_CarsParked').val(), $('#dashboard-report-range').data('daterangepicker').startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), $('#dashboard-report-range').data('daterangepicker').endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            $('#label_RevenueWithTip').getData($('#label_RevenueWithTip').val(), $('#dashboard-report-range').data('daterangepicker').startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), $('#dashboard-report-range').data('daterangepicker').endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            $('#label_Revenue').getData($('#label_Revenue').val(), $('#dashboard-report-range').data('daterangepicker').startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), $('#dashboard-report-range').data('daterangepicker').endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));            
        });
        $('#dashboard-report-range span').html(moment().subtract('days', 29).format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + moment().format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        $('#dashboard-report-range').show();
});

/*Defining getData*/
$.fn.getData = function (valet, start, end) {
        var tbody = $(this);
        var params = {
            valetlot_id: valet,
            start_date: start,
            end_date: end
        };
        var str = jQuery.param(params);
        $.getJSON('http://api.valetpayapp.com/phptest/dashboard_fetch_valet_transactions.php?callback=?', str, function (data) {
            tbody.html(''); /*Clearing the table*/
            /*Populating the table*/
            $.each(data, function (i, f) {
                var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.Date + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Status + "</td>" + "<td> " + f.BusinessName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.TotalAmount + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.ParkingRate + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Tip + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.PromoCode + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.PromoDiscount + "</td>" + "</tr>";
                tbody.append(tblRow);
            });
        });
};
```

To learn more about bootstrap date range picker, take a look at this https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker

Comment: Thank u soooooooo much @vbn  its working... I have one more doubt, how to bind first value in select box automatically after loading the web page.

Comment: I have one more [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517021/how-to-get-all-json-values-in-line-chart) Please check the given link do the needful... Thanks @vbn

Comment: hi @vbn i have one more doubt... am set 'start_date' & 'end_date' statically in this code. now am gonna use bootstrap datepicker with this code. my doubt is while am selecting the date rage (eg: 1-1-1014 to 1-3-2014) like this, the table also show the date within the date range. how to get this.

Comment: Do you mean how to get the value in the datepicker? `$('#datepicker').val()`

Comment: Hi @vbn i have update my above code please check it... thanks

Comment: Oh, u meant `daterangepicker` not `datepicker`. This sounds like another question :) but anyway, look at my edited answer and let me know if that is what you're after.

Comment: Ya its working good @vbn ... but i want to add one more API link with this and try to show the data in div tag but the table data got merged  with the div data while change the select box value. am tried to fix the error. can u help me to fix it. i update your code and highlight it with /* Update code */ please check your given answer and help me... thanks

Comment: I dont really understand how the data in the table got merged with the div as I havent seen your HTML code. However, looking at the updated code, the way you're using the `getData` function is wrong. The object calling the function must be a `table` as it's constructing `<tr>` and `<td>` inside. Another point in your code is `$('#label_CarsParked').getData($('#label_CarsParked').val()`. This makes me confused as to whether `label_CarsParked` is a div or `select` or `input`. Because, if it is a `div`, you shouldn't call `$('#label_CarsParked').val()`

Comment: To add another url, you can just make it as a param to the function `$.fn.getData = function (valet, start, end, url)` then you'd call `$.getJSON(url, str, function (data) { ...`

Comment: Hi @vbn i tried it lot, still the table data got merged with the Div element. I have update my HTML code and yours $.fn.getData pls check the update. My issue is when select the dateragepicker value table shows its data perfectly but the div block shows both the div data and table data. I think the problem is in var tbody = $(this); am not sure about this. Please check it... thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how it looks on your end but as I said before `$('#label_CarsParked').getData($(this).val(), ` didn't make sense. This could be the reason it's merging. Please read my previous comment carefully! Whichever calls `getData` will be the `this` in that function.